# Disappearing menu items add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm having problems with disappearing menu items in a sheets-addon.

My code looks like this:

```
  function onInstall() {
  onOpen()
}
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var items = [{
          name: 'Start syncing',
          functionName: 'start'
      }
               ,
      {
          name: 'Stop syncing',
          functionName: 'removeAllTriggers'
      }
  ];
  ss.addMenu('Custom Menu', items);}
```

The result looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrYgK.png

I've been having a lot of inconsistent results. 
The menu used to appear, and work as expected.
Then suddenly on reopening the spreadsheet the day after the menu would look like the screenshot above.
Upon removing and re-installing the addon, Google asks for an extra "Offline use"-permission.
Usually this fixed the issue, but recently even after granting this extra permission the menu-items still aren't appearing.

Comment: Tried it in my end, your code is working. Some additional scenarios I've test is change my system clock (+1 day). Closed the browser and view the spreadsheet again, and still the custom menu is still viewable.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I had some errors in the rest of my code. Also if you are using libraries `Resources/libraries`, make sure you have proper access rights. Also during the development of an add-on, menu loads after a short delay. When you will publish the app, delay will go away.

Moreover you can try using [createAddonMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createaddonmenu) from UI class to create menu.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start syncing', 'start')
      .addItem('Stop syncing', 'removeAllTriggers')
      .addToUi();
}
```